# How to make a URL mod redirect (.htaccess) more fool proof?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following redirects, which partially work fine but are not quite fool-proof.

URL (**works**):

```
example.com/test123
example.com/test123/hello
```

The **.htaccess** I have:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&mode=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Although it works fine, when the user enters "example.com/test123", but not for "example.com/test123/". For some reason putting the "/" at the end of the URL takes the page to 404.

The following URLs (**do not work**) for the above (.htaccess) re-direct entries (because of the **"/"** at the end):

```
example.com/test123/
example.com/test123/hello/
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This rule should work with `example.com/test123/` also. What is your Apache version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### As @anubhava observed,

your rules work for me even with URL 404 errors for you. So please test, by adding a line, by disactivating MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&mode=$2 [L,QSA]
```

#### At the meantime, to rewrite http://www.example.com/test123/hello/,

you should re-program your HTML documents, a painful change: all resource files must be used in absolute path, as for *.css, *.js, *.png, ... And they must not be rewritten. In this case style.css will not match RewriteRules, so remains untouched - we have luck!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mystyles/style.css" />
```

Instead of relative path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles/style.css" />
```

The same change is required for *.js, *.png, ...

Comment: I noticed that this is not going to the 404 page now, but it is going to the index.php page without the stylesheet. So everything is showing up all misplaced.

Comment: `\w` cannot match a dot hence `\w+` won't match `style.css`

Answer (score 0):

One can assume that a trailing slash is never required. If that's the case, you could add a rewrite rule to remove the trailing slash, making the redirect always work.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure the rewrite occurs **BEFORE** the redirect!

Comment: After I added this, now "example.com/test123/" is being redirected to "example.com/var/www/test123". My application is installed inside the "/var/www/" folder.

Comment: Is there a way to do the reverse, i.e. "example.com/test123" will always redirect to "example.com/test123/" instead.